# Definition of Boolean truth value and its expression in meta theory.

Tags: logic, set-theory

In Bell's set theory book, the statement 'the axiom scheme of separation is true in $V^{B}$(Boolean valued model) for any complete Boolean algebra $B$' is proved in $ZFC$
by fixing arbitrary formula $\phi$
and showing
$\forall u\exists v\forall x[x\in v \iff x\in u \land\phi(x)]$ is true in $V^{B}$.

And he says that $ZFC$ cannot completely formalize the construction of the Boolean value $\Vert{\sigma}\Vert^{B}$ for arbitrary sentence $\sigma$.

My question is, how can I express the above statement in first order arithmetic($PA$)?

I wish to express in $PA$ that if $\phi(x)$ is a formula in which $v$ is not free, then $ZFC\vdash\Vert\forall u\exists v\forall x[x\in v \iff x\in u \land\phi(x)]\Vert=1$

But I don't know whether $\Vert\forall u\exists v\forall x[x\in v \iff x\in u \land\phi(x)]\Vert$ can be expressed for arbitrary $\phi$ in the meta theory $PA$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difficulty expressing $\Vert\forall u\exists v\forall x[x\in v \iff x\in u \land\phi(x)]\Vert$ in the *meta*theory.  Specifically, you can write down an algorithm that takes a formula $\sigma$ in the language of ZFC and outputs a formula $\varphi$ in the language of ZFC that defines (with $B$ as a parameter) $\Vert{\sigma}\Vert^{B}$ (that is, $\Vert{\sigma}\Vert^{B}$ is the unique $x$ such that $\varphi(x,B)$).  This is just the usual definition of $\Vert{\sigma}\Vert^{B}$ by recursion on formulas.

What ZFC cannot formalize is that ZFC cannot define a function that takes a formula $\sigma$ as an input and outputs the *value* of $\Vert{\sigma}\Vert^{B}$.  It can take $\sigma$ and output a formula that *defines* this value, but it can't actually evaluate this defining formula to get a value of $B$.  This is an instance of the non-definability of truth: ZFC can't define a function that takes a formula $\varphi$ and outputs the unique set that $\varphi$ defines (if $\varphi$ defines a unique set), because ZFC can't define what it means for a set to satisfy $\varphi$.  This is not a problem for expressing a purely syntactic statement like $ZFC\vdash\Vert\forall u\exists v\forall x[x\in v \iff x\in u \land\phi(x)]\Vert=1$, though, since this only requires a formula that defines $\Vert\forall u\exists v\forall x[x\in v \iff x\in u \land\phi(x)]\Vert$ in the language of set theory.